# C++ Template Class method implementation within a cpp file

Tags: c++, class, templates, implementation

i am struggling with the C++ template concept.
What i have is something like that:

abstractClass.h:

```
namespace a {
  namespace b {
    template <typename RETURNTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
    class AbstractClass {

      protected:
        RETURNTYPE rtype;
        DATATYPE dtype;
        std::size_t countValues;

      public:
        explicit AbstractClass(DATATYPE _dtype, size_t _countValues):
          rtype(0),
          dtype(_data), 
          countValues(_countValues)  {

          }           
          virtual void process() = 0;
    };
  }   // namespace worker
}   // namespace eetneon
```

derivedClass.h

```
#include "abstractClass.h"

namespace a {
  namespace b {
    template <typename RETURNTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
    class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass<RETURNTYPE, DATATYPE> {

      public:
        DerivedClass(DATATYPE _data, size_t _countValues): 
          AbstractClass<RETURNTYPE, DATATYPE>(_data, _countValues) {
        }

        void process() override;

    };
  }   // namespace worker
}   // namespace eetneon
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to implement the void process() method within a *.cpp file or do I have to put the implementation in the header file, so the compiler can see it (I read something like that lately), because shit just got real, when i tried to put the implementation stuff away from the *.h file. Are there any sophisticated approaches to solve this problem? Everything i found until now seems a bit rough around the edges!

Thanks for your time and please excuse my horrible english.

Sincerely
Hymir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: yes it's possible, but only for a limited set of template arguments. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I am just looking for a suitable way to keep the code clean and structured. I mean, defining all templated classes at some point doesn't seem like the idea behind the concept of templates does it? Furthermore filling my header files with implementation stuff is also not the way i want to go if there would be any alternatives!

Comment: Take a look at "extern templates" for C++11.

Comment: Wait for concepts and put templates in the interface.

Comment: I will check the extern templates! Seems like a good solution. What do you mean with "put templates in the interface"? Can you give me a short example pls?

Comment: @Peregring-lk if i got this straight, i have to declare the templated class in my main.cpp for instance like extern class DerivedClass<int, int> and also have to declare it within the implementation file of this class like

Comment: `template class DerivedClass<int,float>`?

Comment: @Hymir I have never used `extern template`s yet, but, under my understanding, you have to do exactly what you have written, because the `template class DerivedClass<int, float>;` explicitly instantiate the template.

Comment: Ok! Thanks alot for all your help!